# CSS use not for TH hover in table TR

Tags: html, css

In `table` I'm using this below CSS for highlight `tr`s and I want to use `:not` for `th`

HTML:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table tr:hover  {
    background-color:#fff;
}
table th:hover  {
    background-color:none !important;
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't work. all columns need to be wrapped in `<tr>`. Including the random `<th>` tags you have at the top

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/3nPgA/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scope the selector to the `tbody`, not the `thead`.

```
tbody tr:hover  {
    background-color:#fff;
}
tbody th:hover  {
    background-color:none !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bpZX/1/

Comment: @TilwinJoy That's interesting that without the actual `<thead>` the browser considers the floating `<tr>` as an additional `<tbody>` so the hover selector triggers. http://jsfiddle.net/3bpZX/1/ Inspect the output in firebug/chrome dev.